# SSL verification error at depth 3: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)

Tags: plugins, ssl-certificate, vagrant, verify, vagrant-plugin

Error while installing vagrant plugin "vagrant-vbguest"

I run the command "vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest"[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BINhg.jpg)
It says it could be transient connectivity issues or proxy filtering rejecting access to a configured plugin source.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the vagrant tag states: VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.